# jQuery background image transition

Tags: jquery, css

I have a div that has a 'home.jpg' image as background and I want the background to be 'another_image.jpg' when I click something. The thing is that I want the new background to fadeIn and not just to appear (by doing some .css('background', url('another_image.jpg')); )

Is there a way to do that? I've tried the bgImageTransition plugin but it just adds another element on top of the div I had...

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do this is to fade in another element with the new background.

Alternatively, you could change the background immediately, then create a new element with the old background and fade it *out*.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [this blog post](http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations/) about animating background images... it is a very cool effect. All you would have to do is turn your two images into a sprite and use that script.

[Here is the demo](http://snook.ca/technical/jquery-bg/).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: added a cross-fade effect: http://jsfiddle.net/8vHa2/3/

(Click the JQuery logo)

Keep in mind that this kind of effects need a second element to be faded out or in, so my recommendation is for you to stick with the plugin you were trying.

Comment: He probably wants a cross-fade.

Comment: @SLaks - Well, then he has no choice but to fadeOut the first elements over a second one like you suggested, I've edited my example with a cross-fade solution.